# ¿Por que me da error al reconocer imagen en PHP?

Tags: php

Quisiera saber a que se debe este error, ya eh puesto todas las validaciones correctamente pero al parecer me sigue diciendo que existe un error en mi variable `$archivo`.

**HTML**

```
<form action="reg.php" method="post">
        <div class="inicio">
            <h1>Registro</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="_name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" name="_lastName">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido Materno" name="_secondName">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Correo" name="_email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Contraseña" name="_password">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Repetir Contraseña" name="_repPassword">
            <input type="file" class="btn-img" name="up-image" id="up-image">
            <button class="btn-main">Registrar Usuario</button>
            <span><a href="./index.php">Cancelar</a></span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['_name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['_name'];
    $lastName = $_POST['_lastName'];
    $secondName = $_POST['_secondName'];
    $email = $_POST['_email'];
    $password = $_POST['_password'];
    $repPassword = $_POST['_repPassword'];

    if ($_FILES['up-image']['error']>0) {
        echo "Error al cargar el archivo";
    } else {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $newId = $date->format('H-i-s');
        $ruta = 'files/'.$newId.'/';
        $archivo = $ruta.$_FILES['up-image']['name'];

        if (!file_exists($ruta)) {
            mkdir($ruta);
        }

        if(!file_exists($archivo)){
            $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES['up-image']['tmp_name'], $archivo);
            if ($resultado) {
                echo ' Archivo guardado <br>';
            } else {
                echo ' Error al guardar el archivo <br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'El archivo ya existe <br>';
        }
    }

    echo 'Los datos fueron almacenados correctamente' . '<br>';
}

echo $name.'<br>'.$lastName.'<br>'.$secondName.'<br>'.$email.'<br>'.$password.'<br>'.$repPassword;
```

> Error
>
> Notice: Undefined index: up-image in C:\xampp\htdocs\FormPHP\reg.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: up-image in C:\xampp\htdocs\FormPHP\reg.php on line 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar archivos usando `form`, debes indicar el atributo [`enctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form#Atributos) igual a `multipart/form-data`, que según la documentación:

> Usar este valor si se está usando el elemento `<input>` con el atributo `type` ajustado a `"file"`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<form action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- resto del código -->
</form>
```

**Sugerencia:**

Una validación que podrías agregar es chequear que la variable está definida:

```
if (!isset($_FILES['up-image'])) { echo "Error: no se envió el archivo."; }
else if ....
```

Comment: Gracias eso no lo sabia, definitivamente me fue de mucha utilidad y resolviste mi duda completamente.